# Relative Parent div same height as absolute child div

Tags: html, css, css-position, parent-child

I have a div in my website which refuses to get the height of the children.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="parent" >      
    <div class="child">
        <center>Section 2</center>
        <div><p>Hello</p></div>
        <div><p>Test</p></div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#parent{
   background: #bc401c;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
}

.child{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   max-width: 900px;
   min-height: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
 }
```

When I inspect the divs in the browser the child looks fine, and gets the proper height but the parent is like having no height at all. 
Is it possible to make the parent get the height of the child?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try removing `position: absolute` and maybe use `height:100%; width:100%` instead.

Comment: *"parent is like having no height"*: What is the parent of `#parent`? Does that parent has height/width set?

Comment: BTW `<center>` has been deprecated in HTML5 and should no longer be used.

Comment: here is a jsfiddle maybe could help: http://jsfiddle.net/53ZYH/

Comment: I do not want to remove the position absolute, because then other divs in my page are messed up

Comment: thanks I will remove <center>.

Comment: @novellino then you should use javascript. I can't see other way.

Comment: @novellino: Looks just fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/R68Hv/ [Notice the difference ?]

Comment: @novellino: Even your fiddle works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/53ZYH/1/ [Notice the difference ?]

Comment: Ok @abhitalks if I add height: 100% to html and body works. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Mr_Green maybe also it is better to try remove position absolute. Thanks

Comment: @novellino: The reason is that for percent units to work, you need to set width/height on its immediate parent (not necessarily html/body).

Comment: I don't understand, if you want to make the parent be the same dimensions as the child, but the child being positioned relative will break the layout, then the parent with the child dimensions would also break the layout

Comment: @Pete: I can understand your concern. Actually if you see the op's code, he has mixed up a couple of things. e.g. child is absolutely positioned within a relative parent which is correct, but then he adds a width/height to be 100%? If it is absolutely positioned then top/left should be the way to go, but he has both. Then, there is a right:0 as well. So, I simply ignored his positioning (doesn't matter in his use-case) and pointed the first problem of percent units.